# Char equals hex char?

Tags: java, char, hex

How to understand my char value is equal  to hex char in java? Like this?

```
boolean isEqual(char ch) {
    char hex = 0xFF;    
    return hex == ch;
}
```

Comment: `return ch == 0xFF ? true : false;`

Comment: It's a habit, I like to return explicit values. +1, ternary can be dropped.

Comment: But It does not work like you said.

Comment: Explain exactly what you want it to do? Do you always want to compare it to `0xff` or do you want to compare to other values as well?

Comment: I always want to it to 0xff. For example, ch is 'a'. How to compare them? @RealSkeptic

Comment: In that case, the answer you got is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isEqual(char ch) {
    return ch == '\u00FF';
}
```

As you know, char is 16 bit, 2 bytes. Hence the code above is clearest.
However many other programming languages, i.e. C and C++, have a tradition of char == byte.